# Passing multiple parameters to NodeJS callback using export module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, callback

Scenarios 1:

I have two file in my atom project `weather.js` and `exmaple.js` and  weather is using export module to export everything to example.js and  in turn example.js is using require module

my weather.js

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports= function(justAnothercallback) 
{
    justAnothercallback('This is from weather');
}
```

myExample.js

```
var fromWeather = require('./weather.js');
fromWeather(function(weather){
    console.log(weather); 
});
```

If I do Node `myExample.js` the output is :
This is from weather

Scenarios 2:
Now I just pass one more callback in my `weather.js`

```
module.exports= function(justAnothercallback, SecondCallback) {
    justAnothercallback('This is from weather');
    SecondCallback('This is second callback)');
}
```

And my example.js is modified to accommodate the second callback function !!

```
var fromWeather = require('./weather.js');
fromWeather(function(weather, anotherfunc){
    console.log(weather);
    console.log(anotherfunc);
});
```

From the terminal we get :

/>node example-callback.js 
**This is from weather
undefined**
/Users/NodeCourse/async/weather.js:7
        SecondCallback('This is second callback)');
        ^

TypeError: SecondCallback is not a function
    at module.exports (/Users/oogway/NodeCourse/async/weath

**My question is are they not the same** , I just added one more callback and it barfed !! why !!?? but it works fine if I pass just one callback ..
Please help one this .

Answer (score 1):

In your code here, you are only passing **one** callback with **two** parameters

```
var fromWeather = require('./weather.js');
  fromWeather(function(weather, anotherfunc){
    console.log(weather);
    console.log(anotherfunc);
  });
```

This is what **two callbacks** would look like

```
var fromWeather = require('./weather.js');
  fromWeather(function(){
    console.log('Hello from callback 1');
  }, function(){
    console.log('Hello from callback 2');
  });
```